# Is a class destruct a reliable way to always execute something at script end?

Tags: php

I was thinking about doing something like this

```
<?php
/** efficient log writing system */
class LogSystem{

    const LOG_FOLDER = "./whatever/";

    protected $logRows = [];

    public function log( string $what ){
        $this->logRows[] = date("h:i:s").": ".$what;
    }

    function __destruct(){
        if( !empty($this->logRows) ){
            $filename = date("Y-m-d").".log";
            $cnt = implode( PHP_EOL, $this->logRows ).PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
            file_put_contents( Self::LOG_FOLDER.$filename, $cnt, FILE_APPEND );
        }
    }
}
```

Today the server this would be executed on stopped because of a very unusual hardware problem. This got me thinking: **can I reasonably be sure that the __destruct of this class will always manage to write its array?**

Comment: Have you tried running this code? What happened?

Comment: If the whole computer halts unexpectedly (due to a critical hardware fault) before the destruct is called, then clearly that code would not run - no code of any sort, even the O/S, would run in that scenario.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor tells you the times when destructors are called. But of course that assumes that the PHP runtime is still working.

Comment: Personally, I’d have a method called `flush()`. Then I’d include logic in `log()` to test the size of the log buffer and automatically call `flush()` as needed, just to keep the buffer low. Then I’d manually call `flush` at the end of my code. You could include a call to flush in the destructor, maybe, with a note saying that a manual call was missed, too. Actually, I’d probably just write to the file each time, no need to buffer. Actually, I’d probably just use Monolog.